# curlコマンドでhtmlが途中までしか取得できない

Tags: aws, curl

AWS上で以下のコマンドを実行すると、下図のように途中で止まりカーソルも返ってきません。
原因の特定や問題の切り分けができず困っています。
解決方法をご存知の方がいましたら、ご教授頂けますと幸いです。

**実行したコマンド:**

```
$ curl http://store.zexy.net/etc/wedgwood.php
```

**結果:**

[image: curl_on_aws]

#### 試したこと

・複数回やっても同様の事象が発生します（再現性あり）。
・同様のcurlコマンドをローカルPC(OSX)や別のサーバ（CentOS)で実行した場合は、正常終了しました
・wget でも、同様に問題が発生しました
・curl http：//（ここに上記ドメインが入ります)/　は正常終了しました（問題なくデータ取得できました）
・curl http://（ここに上記ドメインが入ります)/etc/baccarat.php も正常終了
・pythonで、requests.get()でも同様にプログラムがとまったままで取得できませんでした
・wget、pythonともローカルなどでは正常終了しました

Comment: `curl -0 http://store.zexy.net/etc/wedgwood.php` とするとどうなりますか？

Comment: 上記だと正常終了します（問題なしです）。 ありがとうございます。 「-0」オプション調べてみます。分からなかったら再度ご質問させてください。

Comment: となりますと、`HTTP 1.0` では OK で `HTTP 1.1` では NG という事ですね…`store.zexy.net` 側の問題ではないでしょうか。

Comment: なるほど。少し前に質問をちょっと編集させていただいたのですが、store.zexy.netや、store.zexy.net/etc/baccarat.phpは、‌​問題なかったのでです。また、ローカルPCが別サーバからは、-0オプションなしでも正常に取得できます。

Comment: 参考情報として、こちらの環境は Ubuntu Linux 16.04, curl 7.47.0 なのですが、同じ場所(`leftnavi start`)で止まります。`-0` オプションでは取得できます。

Comment: debian8.5 (Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2)でもHTTP1.1でも正常終了しました。

Comment: 「Path MTU Discovery ブラックホール」のような気がします。

Comment: Teratail に同様の質問 [curlが最後で止まる原因について](https://teratail.com/questions/16396) があって、HTTP 1.1 の chunked transfer encoding が原因だろうとの事です。ただ、HTTP 1.1 でも正常終了する場合があるので何とも言えませんね…

Comment: 「Path MTU Discovery ブラックホール」...勉強になります。MTUを変更せず、HTTP1.1のままで回避する方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: 一応、`curl -H 'Expect: 100-continue' http://store.zexy.net/etc/wedgwood.php` とする事でコンテンツを全て取得する事ができました。`100 Continue response` については、コメント欄に書くには量が多いので検索してみて下さい。

Comment: 'Expect: 100-continue'でできました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

以下の通り`-H 'Expect: 100-continue'`をオプションに追加することでコンテンツをすべて取得することができました(コメント欄でのやり取りより)

```
curl -H 'Expect: 100-continue' http://store.zexy.net/etc/wedgwood.php
```